# Horizon not processing jobs after Laravel upgrade from 9 to Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-horizon, horizon

I have made an upgrade on Laravel from 9 to 10 and now my laravel horizon is not processing jobs. Jobs are only processed if i run commands :
php artisan queue:listen and php artisan queue:work --once.

If i run the command php artisan queue:work jobs are not processed as well. This commands are working fine and most importantly php artisan horizon is working as expected on laravel 9. I am unable to figure out what is causing this issue.

Horizon dashboard :
[image]

Here is php artisan command how it looks all the time, no errors are printed
[image]

Comment: But, horizon uses `php artisan horizon`, `php artisan queue:work` and `queue:listen` have nothing to do with Horizon: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/horizon#running-horizon

Comment: this is correct but it does same as artisan queues as i understand, and on laravel 9 when i run php artisan horizon the jobs are been run, but with upgrade to laravel 10 php artisan horizon stopped working

Comment: Then, it is another issue, but `php artisan queue:xxx` never interacts with `php artisan horizon` at all. Do you have any errors at all? Is horizon able to start and just does nothing? If you go to the horizon dashboard, what do you see? You need to add more info please

Comment: I have added image from horizon dashboard and php artisan horizon command output ( no output at all ). When there is no job in queue there is only 1 process running when new job is created process count is 10 but the job is not been processed.

Comment: So, the horizon does not have a worker listening to a queue, you have an issue there. I think there is a command `horizon:list` or `horizon:status`, one should list the available workers and what queues it is listening to. Check that out and post the images of those

Comment: Horizon list is showing the supervisor and status , here is output of commandwww@3bca117a745a:/var/www$ php artisan horizon:list
+-------------------+------+--------------+---------+
| Name              | PID  | Supervisors  | Status  |
+-------------------+------+--------------+---------+
| 3bca117a745a-PZgp | 5972 | supervisor-1 | running |
+-------------------+------+--------------+---------+

Comment: Is your `QUEUE_DRIVER` in your `.env` set to `redis`?

Comment: yeap it is set to redis

Comment: I have worked with queues today only and i can see some difference. Once i add implements ShouldQueue to Job than the jobs are not processed. If i remove ShouldQueue implementation on jobs than command php artisan queue:work executes the job , otherwise it will not execute. When implement ShouldQueue is present command php artisan queue:work --once and php artisan queue:listen works / execute the job. I am confused ...